# Equivalent of OS X's Shift Apple-3/4 in Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows, macos, screenshot

Is there a screenshot equivalent of OS X's Shift-Apple-3 or 4 built into Windows 2003 Server?

Just to clarify,

I have this Win 2003  box on a KVM switch .. and since I am at a 95% OS X shop, the only keyboard I had hanging around is a Mac keyboard  -- So I was looking for a way to get a screenshot  from the server sans a PC Keyboard .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print Screen is actually just F13 with a specific function.

Depending on the Apple keyboard model (not all Apple keyboards follow the same mapping) the following ***MAY*** work:

```
Apple+Control+Shift+F13
```

Some other combination of modifiers + F13 may also work

Another option would be to use the Windows On Screen Keyboard

On XP you get to this via

```
Start-Programs-Accessories-Accessibility-On Screen Keyboard
```

should be somewhere similar on 2003

Answer (score 1):

Attach a windows keyboard or use 3rd party software that can be set to use a different keystroke - [Ashampoo Magical Snap Free](http://www.ashampoo.com/frontend/products/php/product.php?session_langid=2&idstring=0124) for example.